# How to set the line color of geom_point in ggplot2 to the fill color of geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am using ggplot2 in R. I would like to specify the line color of `geom_point()` to use the fill color of `geom_smooth()` automatically based on the used theme. (In my actual data there are many more groups of lines each having their own default themed color.) How can I do that?

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
mtcars$mpg <- 1
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=hp,y=wt,fill=mpg,colour=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

Comment: Your code already results in the same colors for the points and the smoother lines. Are you saying you want to change those colors? If so, add `scale_colour_gradient` and `scale_fill_gradient` and specify the same color values.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You want Fill and Colour to be the same? ggplot does that automatically, In your example both the line and the dots are the same color.

Comment: Hmm the background color of the smooth plot ( the error range ) is a lighter blue than then the actual line. I would like to have the points the same lighter color.

Comment: The confidence band on the smooth line is a lighter shade because ggplot reduces the alpha blending on the fill for that so that other plot elements are visible and not obscured by the confidence band.

Comment: `geom_smooth` uses a fill color with alpha transparency beeing 0.4, see e.g. `geom_point(alpha = .4, shape = 21, size = 8)`.

Comment: Thanks for that info Luke. I have tried using alpha  argument on geom_point() the problem is that there are many overlapping points and therefore the color will become darker, unlike when you would set the actual color with alpha=1. I guess I will have to manually set the colors then.

Comment: The problem is that the alpha property sets the alpha for each point and not for the entire layer as I would expect.

Comment: FWIW, setting the alpha transparency for each point is the intended purpose of alpha transparency, to allow for lighter/darker areas to reveal areas of over plotting. The idea that the shades are "additive" is sort of the whole point.

Comment: No I disagree, I think the alpha should be applied to the layer not the points. This has been addressed in https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1371 . For the moment it seems it is not possible what I want.